# How Google protobuf format reduces size of the object after it encoded

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;

import sample.ProtoObj.Attachment;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        POJO pojo = new POJO();
        pojo.setContent("content");
        List<sample.POJO.Attachment> att = new ArrayList<POJO.Attachment>();
        sample.POJO.Attachment attach = pojo.new Attachment();
         attach.setName("Attachment Name");
         attach.setId("0e068652dbd9");
         attach.setSize(1913558);
         att.add(attach);
         pojo.setAttach(att);
         byte[] byyy = SerializationUtils.serialize(pojo);
         System.out.println("Size of the POJO ::: "+byyy.length);

         ProtoObj tc = new ProtoObj();
         List<Attachment> attachList = new ArrayList<ProtoObj.Attachment>();
         Attachment attach1 = tc.new Attachment();
         attach1.setName("Attachment Name");
         attach1.setId("0e068652dbd9");
         attach1.setSize(1913558);
         attachList.add(attach1);
         tc.setContent("content");
         tc.setAttach(attachList);

         byte[] bhh = tc.getProto(tc);

         System.out.println("Size of the PROTO ::: "+bhh.length);

    }

}
```

I have used above program to compute the size of the encoded/Serialized Object using Protobuf and POJO. Both the objects handle same set of the data. But the output shows drastic difference in the size of the object.

**Output:**

```
Size of the POJO ::: 336
Size of the PROTO ::: 82
```

Also I have read the below link to know how google protobuf formats affect the size of the encoded object.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

But I'm unable to understand it. Please explain me to understand simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf doesn't send the schema alongside with the data. So both sides need to have the schema in order to deserialise passed data.

Because of that you can optimise and put each field right after another. Something like this:

> AttachmentName0e068652dbd91913558

And all this in binary format. This in JSON would look like:

> {"name": "AttachmentName", "id": "0e068652dbd9", "size": "1913558"}

As you can see the schema is encoded in the serialised message itself.

I'm not completely aware of Java SerialisationUtils, but I think they pass or encode the schema also and that's why you see this size difference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Without schema( i believe that it represents variable name like name, id) how they will differentiate the value while de-serializing it.

Comment: As I said, both sides need the schema - when serialising I'm using the schema to serialise, and when someone else is deserialising he need to have the exact same schema in order to deserialise. It's just the fact that both sides have the schema in advance and didn't receive it with the data itself.

Comment: Ok one more doubt that new schema addition will not affect old encoded object as we need to maintain unique number in proto definition. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Unique numbers in proto files are used just for this. You also have required fields, which when changed lead to exact same problem.